# Logic errors within java segment

Tags: java

The following Java code segment is supposed to print, as a double, the mean average of a sequence of non-negative integers entered by the user.  A negative input signals the end of the sequence (it is not itself part of the sequence).  However, the code is not working. I am supposed to find 4 logic errors within this segment. Please help me find the 4 logic errors?? I know one is its integer division.

```
public class practice
{
   public static void main (String[]args)
   {
   int sum = 0;
   int numVals = 0;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println(("enter next integer (-ve to stop): ")); 
   int i = scan.nextInt(); 

   while (i > 0)
   {
       sum = sum + i; 
       numVals = numVals + 1; 
    }

   System.out.println("average = " + sum / numVals); 
}
```

}

Comment: It would be unfair for us to deprive you of this learning experience :)

Comment: i am unsure why it does not print the second print statement. when i add it in to the while loop it becomes an infinite loop. i feel like the while loop should be changed to an if statement???

Comment: you can try running it :P I bet you can find some problems.

Comment: The point of your homework is for you to learn to do this work.  If you are having problems with it, you should go to your Prof/TA, this isn't really the place to obtain tutorials in how to read code.

Comment: @lewisfurlan-lowry the loop is needed to input a *sequence*. Perhaps the input should be inside the loop ;) BTW I can see more than 4 errors in you include non-logic errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is the specification of someone's assignment.

Comment: and you are correct, infinite loop, while i>0 , and what is the value of i in each iteration?

Comment: @Zéychin yes it does compile... or what do you mean that it shouldn't compile?

Comment: I need to go take a nap. Ignore my comment.

Comment: @Zéychin its okay :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you full solution, however, it'll be helpful if you pay attention to:

1. `int` division as you said,
2. does your loop terminate? Is someone changing `i`? Hint: No, and
3. how do you ask for input? Do you see any loops there? Why it's asking you for only one input?

<sup>Not an error, but pay attention to Java Naming Conventions, class name should begin with upper case</sup>

Comment: @Zéychin I don't see any compilation errors.. :/

Comment: Nevermind. I am need my nap. xD. Ignore me.

Comment: @Zéychin Need for naps and compilation errors have very strong connection ;)

Comment: Need for naps and misreading `String[]args` as `String[args` are strongly connected.

Answer (score 1):

Since the homework is for logic errors, I could point out other errors.

- the class name should start with upper case letter.
- the println doesn't need two nested parenthesis.
- the `sum` should be a long rather than an int to avoid overflows.

Comment: ... for the nested parenthesis :)